# How do i append in a dictionary that is made using inputs from a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, dictionary

This is my code:

```
fh = open('students.txt', 'r')


def dictio_maker(direc):
    count = 0
    for line in fh:
        line = line.split(" ") #Separates each string in each line
        student_num = line[0] #Sets the first element of the list "line" as the student_num
        student_name = line[1] #Sets the second element of the list "line" as the student_name
        student_grade = line[2] #Sets the third element of the list "line" as the student_grade

        count =+ 1 #To change the key names
        direc[student_num] = [student_name,student_grade]
        student_num = "student_num" + str(count) #Changes the key names for the next iteration
        student_grade = "student_grade" + str(count)
        student_name = "student_name" + str(count)
    print(direc)
    return direc

def append(direc):
    x = input('Do you want to modify an entry? (yes/no)')
    if x == "yes":
        while True:
            try:
                student_num = int(input('Enter student num: '))
            except ValueError:
                print('Please enter a valid input')
                continue
            break

        if student_num in direc.keys():
            print('Already existing. Please enter another.')

        else: 
            fh.write(str(student_num) + " ")
            while True:
                try:
                    student_name = input('Enter student name: ' )
                except ValueError:
                    print('Please enter a valid input')
                    continue
                break
            fh.write(str(student_name) + " ")
            while True:
                try:
                    student_grade= float(int(input('Enter student grade: ')))
                except ValueError:
                    print('Please enter a valid input')
                    continue
                break

            fh.write(str(student_grade) + " " + '\n')
            dictio_maker(direc)
            print(direc)    

    else: 
        fh.close()

def main():
    direc= {}
    dictio_maker(direc)
    append(direc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

WHAT IT DOES:
Initially, i have a text file that contains the inputs needed for this program in this format:

```
student_num1 student_name1 student_grade1
student_num2 student_name2 student_grade2
student_num3 student_name3 student_grade3
```

The first function basically turns the lines of text from the input txt file into inputs in my dictionary "direc"

WHAT I WANT TO DO:
Now, what i want to do for my next functions is ask the user if they want to add another entry. If yes, i ask the user for the student number and if the student number does not exist, accept the new values of name and grade and add it to the text file (students.txt). But if the student number exists, ask the user again for another entry (student_number).

THE PROBLEM:
I get an error of:

```
  File "C:/Users/Dust/Desktop/alemios_students_add.py", line 35, in append
    fh.write(str(student_num) + " ")

UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

And i'm also not sure if the code that i did is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have your file in read-only mode:

```
fh = open('students.txt', 'r')
```

You need to change it to:

```
fh = open('students.txt', 'r+')
```

**WARNING**: This solution overwrites existing data in the file!

Comment: My code doesn't detect  on the second  function if the entered student_number already exists in  the dictionary. Why do you think this is so?